# How to know when to use non-parametric coefficient confidence interval estimates for regression?

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, bootstrap, standard-error, asymptotics

Say I have either logistic regression or simple linear regression and I am not sure if I have a moderate number of observations, $n = 40$.

How do I know when to switch to using a non-parametric standard error estimate instead of the Wald intervals? It seems to be we can look at residuals and in particular at the RSS or the Deviance of the residuals and look for their error at different quantiles as a way to test for asymmetry.

Is that sufficient? And even doing that, when to switch to a different standard error calculation? For example, how do I know it's appropriate to bootstrap the confidence intervals or just that the coverage of my standard errors isn't likely to be very good?

Comment: I usually simply generate random data from possible distributions, e.g. normal, contaminated normal, t-distribution etc, with similar parameters to my test data, and then see the impact of using one or another estimator. What are you trying to detect? What are you interested in not missing? What does not matter?

Comment: Use more robust Y-transformation-free semiparametric (ordinal) regression. See [here](https://fharrell.com/post/rpo) for resources.